# Make Rally button and Rally combobox Inline

Tags: css, combobox, inline, rally

I am trying to do basic CSS with rally components.  Currently I am working on getting an xtype 'rallybutton' to be inline with an xtype 'rallyiterationcombobox'.  I am using a CSS file that successfully updates / changes other pieces of the app whose class name I have set manually, but the preset classes on the rally components seem to not be editable with my css file.  I am using Chrome's debugger to look up the class names on each of these components - the rally button has multiple class names depending on where in the html you look: x-btn or x-btn-inner, the rallyiterationcombobox has these: x-form-text, x-form-trigger-wrap, x-form-item-body, and a few others.

I'm trying to use a CSS function that looks like this:

```
.[buttonClass], .[comboboxClass] {
    display: inline;
}
```

with different combinations of names for classes referring to the button and combobox.  [When I put the class names in, I do delete the brackets].  Any help would be appreciated in showing where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the two components I was using, rallyiterationcombobox and rallybutton, were placed into two different containers in my app.  Ext does some magic behind the scenes trying to place each component in their own section of the page, so trying to put them inline with each other was causing problems.  To fix the situation, we put both components into the same container and formatted from there.  Inside each component definition we used the following code

```
cls: 'className'
```

to create a class named 'className' which can then be referred to within the css file.  Inside the css file we used the code

```
.className1 {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
.className2 {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

to set each component in the same line [horizontally], with both components aligned on the left of the app and the component with 'className2' 10 pixels to the right of the component with 'className1'.

Comment: Good find. Thanks for posting your solution!